# docker, связь контейнеров

Tags: docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: 'web:2'
  mysql56:
    image: 'mysql:5.6'
```

когда запускаю docker-compose up -d, создаётся сеть, но контейнеры подключаются к ней под другими именами: <название_проекта>_web_1, <название_проекта>_mysql56_1

Comment: `docker image ls` выполните команду - не висят ли у вас уже запущенные первые?

Comment: имеется ввиду docker ps --all ? нет, остановленных копий нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте свои имена сервисов (такие как у вас имена создаются автоматически):

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    сontainer_name: web
    image: 'web:2'
  mysql56:
    сontainer_name: mysql
    image: 'mysql:5.6'
```

Ссылка на документацию: [вот](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name)

Comment: спасиб добрый человек. а что ж они сначало пишут одно, а потом другое...